# Looking for a medieval store-management game on the TRS-80 Color Computer, might have been code from Rainbow magazine

Tags: identify-this-game, color-computer

Crossposted from [the Science Fiction and Fantasy Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225590/tandy-coco-2-game-involving-managing-a-set-of-shops-in-a-fantasy-world), where it's been unanswered for almost two years.

I'm trying to track down a game I remember playing on our Color Computer 2 (it could have been on the Color Computer 3, although the game was simple enough that I doubt it needed the upgrade). I played it somewhere in the later 80s to the early 90s, the period in which we had this computer before moving to an IBM PC. I'm pretty sure I loaded it off of floppy disks rather than off of a tape or cartridge. It was an entirely text-based game, run through menus, where you ran shops in a medieval world. As I recall it, the businesses had the same names every time, and including at least one case of a pun about a lingerie shop that sold "Knight wear" and I vaguely recall that there was at least one shop devoted to taxes or accounting. There was a standard list of shops every time, and the standard listing only occupied a screen or two, although it was possible to access a much larger list, or pick from that list by typing in that later number. As I recall it, that was part of how I found the lingerie shop, which otherwise might have been considered too naughty to be front and center.

Other than the regular business of investing, there was a way to illicitly access the shops at night, which would lead to something where you were confronting by a set of choices involving knobs of different metals. For some reason, my brain keeps thinking of them as drawers, but doors would make more sense, although part of me still pictures them as stacked on top of each other rather than horizontally placed. At least one of the penalties involved the knob being electrified and one of the knobs was silver. I think I mainly recall this, because this was part of where I'd "hack" the game to avoid a death by using GOTO to hit a more favorable outcome.

I have been unable to find this game listed in the common game lists, but based on my memories of breaking out of execution, listing source lines, and using GOTO statements to force execution to a preferred outcome, this might have been because the game was one my brother had typed in, possibly from *The Rainbow* magazine (I don't believe it's one he wrote on his own, as he never quite hit that level of development). It is possible that it was someone else's hobby project, as he attended occasional meetings in the vicinity of Ashland, KY, maybe in nearby Huntington, WV or one of the nearby towns in Ohio, from which he brought floppies with a range of programs from hobby projects to pirated software that was being passed around.

Unfortunately, it's probably been over 30 years since I played the game, so that's pretty much the extent of the details I can recall, although I'd be glad to answer any questions people might have.